# Manual Mercury Milan is stuck in reverse

Tags: troubleshooting, manual-transmission, mercury, milan

I recently replaced my shifter cable because the car was stuck in gear. After doing this, the Milan was put in reverse and then got stuck. Prior to the replacement, the car was slipping out of 5th gear repeatedly and occasionally out of 3rd and 4th. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you double checked the cable installation? Seems like one possible explanation would be that the cable either slipped or wasn't adjusted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

questions

- does the stick move but the gear is stuck or is the gear stuck and the stick cant even go to neutral?
- what gear was it stuck in before?
- what gear was shifted from when it was shifted to reverse.
- was it able to shift through all the other gears without issue and then became stuck when testing reverse?
- did you adjust the cables properly
- when letting out the clutch is it actually in reverse? or does it simply go nowhere at all? If lightly letting out the clutch does in fact go nowhere disengage the clutch immediately or you can break gear teeth and other things. If the car does go in reverse that is normal. when it goes nowhere you are engaging 2 different gears at the same time. If it is something like first or reverse and fifth you could really do some damage as lots of torque would be placed on 5th gear or whatever the highest gear is for your car. There is a small metal ball that is supposed to prevent this but if its missing then this could be an issue. If the car goes forward but is stuck in reverse then the shifter pin that pushes the forks may have gotten jammed behind one I know this is an issue with suzuki samurai transfer cases. the car being in neutral can also be caused by it jumping behind the forks.
- why did you suspect it was the shifter cable?
- which shifter cable was replaced the forward backward motion one or the left right motion one? Or does that car do something different like twist the cable along with pushing and pulling?